# Best lotto algorithms 7 from 42

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I have been looking for some algorithms  to solve some problems with lottery **7 from 42.**

**My question is** , what is the best algorithm to guess at least 2 numbers from selected 7: example  , I am able to choose 7 numbers from 1 to 42 ,**Now I need at least 2 of my selected numbers from my selected 7 to be in resulted 7.**

After some investigation I have found that algorithm with consecutive numbers is one of the bests.
**Example:** My selection 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 Using such algorithms I have very big chances to guess at least 2 numbers.

I want to know if there are any other  algorithms to resolve my problem.

Thanks for reading.

Some lotto results can be founded here:

http://cyberpredictions.com/Admin/Experiment/GetExperimentById?experimentId=3

Also some statistic here:

http://cyberpredictions.com/Admin/Experiment/DisplayDraawNumberscount?experimentId=3

and here

http://cyberpredictions.com/Admin/Experiment/NotSelectedNumbers?experimentId=3

Comment: "Now I need at least 2 of my selected numbers from my selected 7 to be in resulted 7"... Wow... Can you make it a little less clear, in order to add some challenge to the question?

Comment: Well , in other words I have a chance to make an  forecast of 7 numbers, know the lotto mechanism will extract 7 winning numbers, Know I do not need an algorithm to guess all 7 winning numbers, I need to guess at least 2 numbers.Is it now  clear for you?

Comment: Hmmmm... Not really, to be honest. I will probably have to go over this comment 3 or 4 times in order to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Look again my problem in other words, You have to make an forecast with 7 numbers from 1 to 42.
Lotto mechanism will extract 7 random numbers.
Now condition is : This list of random 7 numbers should contain at least 2 of your foretasted numbers.

Comment: So you're asking for an algorithm to guess correctly randomly selected numbers???

Comment: If the numbers are actually random, then you're not going to find a deterministic algorithm that will (consistently) select them.  Perhaps the better question to ask is: can I buy a bunch of tickets (inter-related in some clever way) that maximizes my expected winnings?  In this case, one might consider purchasing tickets that form a block design (making some guarantee like: every pair of values from the 7 chosen are on at least 1 ticket I bought).

Comment: Yes , but this random is also not so random, If I will choose 7 consecutive numbers I have big chances to guess at least 2 numbers.First i should remove all lust results and so on according to  different algorithms.

Comment: Why do you think choosing $7$ consecutive numbers will have a bigger chance to correctly guess at least $2$ numbers? By symmetry, each number has the same chance of being drawn. So whether your guess is consecutive numbers or not should have no effect on the probability of correct guess.

Comment: Looking to each result of lotto, I can choose 7 consecutive numbers that will contain at least 2 winning numbers, and I think that this is good algorithm when i should extract at least 2 numbers not more.
This algorithm is totally unprofitable when you want to guess all 7 numbers.

Comment: @MDDDC: The term "consecutive" is irrelevant here. The values of the numbers are **meaningless**. You can think of them as different symbols or colors or whatever you'd like to.

Comment: @barak manos Why?

Comment: Because the values of the numbers are irrelevant in a lottery draw. I can't think of any other way to explain it. The chances of drawing any value are equal. The fact that $5$ comes after $6$ in the integer-number field is meaningless here. You could just as well depict each value as a different shape. It is nothing more than a symbol. The amount that is represented by each one of these symbols has no effect on the lottery draw.

Comment: In real, is not so. I think you do not have much experience with lotto.

Comment: @MDDDC In real, it is so. I am curious what kind of investigation did you perform. Since there are only $42$ different numbers, one can always find $2$ among the $7$ chosen numbers, whose difference is less than $7$. Maybe this is the fact you were misled by.

Comment: @MDDDC Nevertheless, there is no better tactic than yours, but ... there is no worse either :)

Answer (score 1):

The probability of drawing any number $n$ from $49$ is $\frac{1}{49}$. If for instance $m$ was already drawn, the probability of drawing $m-1$, $m+1$, or $m+42$ (if applicable), are all equal to $\frac{1}{48}$. What numbers are painted on the balls have no consequence whatsoever on the draw.

> After some investigation I have found that algorithm with consecutive
>   numbers is one of the bests.

I'm sorry to say, but your investigation was flawed.

> Example: My selection $20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27$. Using such algorithms I
>   have very big chances to guess at least $2$ numbers.

Since drawing $\{1, 49\}$ has the same probability as drawing $\{20,21\}$, you did not increase your chances to guess at least $2$ numbers in any way whatsoever.